# Cannot get gdalwarp to work

Tags: gdalwarp

I am having some trouble getting gdalwarp to work. I want to clip my input raster `in.img` to the boundary of a polygon stored in a shapefile `polygon.shp` and save it out as `out.img`. The data type of `in.img` is 32-bit float. The raster cells external to the polygon delineation have a value of 0.0. I figure gdalwarp ought to be able to clip `in.img` to my polygon boundary, effectively setting the external 0.0 values to NoData (that is what I *want* to do, anyway). I am using the following command at the Windows command prompt:

```
gdalwarp -of HFA -cutline polygon.shp in.img out.img
```

The problem is, this doesn't seem to achieve anything. `out.img` is essentially a copy of `in.img` in that the cells external to the polygon boundary are still 0.0—my understanding was that this would only happen if I used the `-crop_to_cutline` flag.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work when I include `-dstnodata -3.40282346639e+038`. Go figure. I'm not sure why it couldn't work this out by itself.

Comment: You might want to accept your answer. I think GDAL is working as it should. It doesn't make assumptions about what you would want with the nodata values. Different people use it after all and those people have different ways of doing things. The -dstnodata switch is a compromise in that direction. And this is a command line tool, not a full GUI package.